# Convert a 3 column file to matrix format

Tags: awk

I have a file format like the example below showing the relationships between 5 individuals including themselves.

```
1   1   1.0
2   1   0.5
3   1   0.1
4   1   0.3
5   1   0.1
2   2   1.0
3   2   0.5
4   2   0.2
5   2   0.3
3   3   1.0
4   3   0.5
5   3   0.3
4   4   1.0
5   4   0.1
5   5   1.0
```

I would like to use AWK to convert it into a full matrix format. I would be necessary to have the rows and columns sorted numerically as in the example.

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   1.0 0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1
2   0.5 1.0 0.5 0.2 0.3
3   0.1 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.3
4   0.3 0.2 0.5 1.0 0.1
5   0.1 0.3 0.3 0.1 1.0
```

I came across a previous thread (below) but the format of the input file is slightly different and i am struggling to adjust it.
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/203483-how-rearrange-matrix-awk.html

How can I perform this transformation?

Comment: Are the keys `A` to `E` representative of the ones in your real data? Is it required that they be sorted alphabetically in the output?

Comment: The real values of A to E are numeric (10 to 13 digits) and yes it would be required that they are sorted numerically

Comment: OK, that's useful information so it should go into your question. Possible [edit] to update your example too, so numbers are used rather than letters (they clearly don't have to contain so many digits!).

Comment: sort of numbers will break your order of letters `A B C D E`, so the letters should be sorted, not numbers (to obtain a matrix)

Comment: after your last edit, the input and output has become unreadable

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest fixed, they just needed indenting.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, ***gawk*** solution:

***matrixize.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }     # output field separator
{
    b[$1];             # accumulating unique indices
    if ($1 != $2) {   
        a[$2][$1] = $3 # set `diagonal` relation between different indices 
    } 
    a[$1][$2] = $3     # multidimensional array (reflects relation `one-to-many`)
}
END {
    asorti(b); h = "";  # sort unique indices
    for (i in b) {
        h = h OFS i     # form header columns
    } 
    print h;            # print header column values
    for (i in b) { 
        row = i;        # index column
        # iterating through the row values (for each intersection point)
        for (j in a[i]) {
            row = row OFS a[i][j]
        } 
        print row  
    }
}
```

***Usage***:

```
awk -f matrixize.awk yourfile
```

The output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   1.0 0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1
2   0.5 1.0 0.5 0.2 0.3
3   0.1 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.3
4   0.3 0.2 0.5 1.0 0.1
5   0.1 0.3 0.3 0.1 1.0
```

Comment: Hi thank you for that. It ran but i seem to get a different order for the ids to what you have got? The input file was tab separated as you had specified.                                                                             
         4 5 1 2 3                                                                              4 1.0 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.5
5 0.1 1.0 0.1 0.3 0.3
1 0.3 0.1 1.0 0.5 0.1
2 0.2 0.3 0.5 1.0 0.5
3 0.5 0.3 0.1 0.5 1.0

Comment: @roddy, I've used the input from your question as is. And I'm obtaining the expected output (as your desired output). Check if your file has leading spaces/tabs (before the first column)

Answer (score 1):

As the upper and lower triangle are identical, would it not be enough to copy each element-pair to both indices in a multi-dimensional array, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```
{ h[$1,$2] = h[$2,$1] = $3 }

END {
  for(i=1; i<=$1; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=$2; j++)
      printf h[i,j] OFS
    printf "\n"
  }
}
```

Run:

```
awk -f parse infile
```

Output:

```
1.0 0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1 
0.5 1.0 0.5 0.2 0.3 
0.1 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.3 
0.3 0.2 0.5 1.0 0.1 
0.1 0.3 0.3 0.1 1.0
```

Note, that this assumes the last line holds the largest indices.

Comment: Thor, The upper and lower are identical I can use either method. I will test them both out on a large file now (9,000 x 9,000) and see which one is faster. As usual thanks to everyone for all the help.

Comment: Having tested the code on my real dataset it looks like it needs the numbering of the ids to be ranked from 1 upwards.

Comment: Hi, Having tested the code on a real dataset it looks like it needs the numbering of the ids to start from 1 upwards. My real ids start at an 8 digit number upwards i.e. 62243121 .                                                                                        
  How would i renumber columns 1 and 2 to start from 1 but ensuring the renumbering of the same id in column 1 is the same as in column 2? 
 Thanks again, Roddy

Comment: @roddy: I'm not following your requirement.  I think you should post a new question with better input/output correspondence to your actual data.